# Antlr 3.4.0 mismatched input for generated parser and not in interpreter

Tags: java, antlr, grammar, antlr3

I know that this has been discussed thousand times but I still cannot figure out why is following grammar failing. In interpreter everything works fine, without any errors or warnings. However when running the generated code, I'm getting mismatched input as shown below.

For this grammar:

```
grammar xxx;

options {
    language = Java;
    output = AST;
}

@members {
  @Override
    public String getErrorMessage(RecognitionException e,
    String[] tokenNames)
    {
        List stack = getRuleInvocationStack(e, this.getClass().getName());
        String msg = null;
        if ( e instanceof NoViableAltException ) {
            NoViableAltException nvae = (NoViableAltException)e;
            msg = " no viable alt; token="+e.token+
            " (decision="+nvae.decisionNumber+
            " state "+nvae.stateNumber+")"+
            " decision=<<"+nvae.grammarDecisionDescription+">>";
        }
        else {
          msg = super.getErrorMessage(e, tokenNames);
        }
        return stack+" "+msg;
    }

  @Override
    public String getTokenErrorDisplay(Token t) {
      return t.toString();
    }
}

obj
      : first=subscription 
      (COMMA other=subscription)*
      ;

subscription
      : ID
      (EQUALS arguments_in_brackets)?
      filters
      ;

arguments_in_brackets
      : LOPAREN arguments ROPAREN
      ;

arguments
      : (arguments_body)
      ;

arguments_body
      : argument (arguments_more)?
      ;

arguments_more
      : SEMICOLON arguments_body
      ;

argument
    : id_equals argument_body
    ;

argument_body
    :   STRING
    |   INT
    |   FLOAT
    ;

filters
      : LSPAREN expression RSPAREN
      ;

expression
      :  or
      ;

or
    : first=and
    (OR^ second=and)*
    ;

and        : first=atom
    (AND^ second=atom)*
    ;

atom
    : filter
    | atom_expression
    ;

atom_expression
    : LCPAREN
    expression
    RCPAREN
    ;

filter
    : id_equals arguments_in_brackets
    ;

id_equals
    : WS* ID WS* EQUALS WS*
    ;

COMMA: WS* ',' WS*;
LCPAREN : WS* '(' WS*;
RCPAREN : WS* ')' WS*;
LSPAREN : WS* '[' WS*;
RSPAREN : WS* ']' WS*;
LOPAREN : WS* '{' WS*;
ROPAREN : WS* '}' WS*;
AND: WS* 'AND' WS*;
OR: WS* 'OR' WS*;
NOT: WS* 'NOT' WS*;
EQUALS: WS* '=' WS*;
SEMICOLON: WS* ';' WS*;

ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
    ;

INT :   '0'..'9'+
    ;

FLOAT
    :   ('0'..'9')+ '.' ('0'..'9')* EXPONENT?
    |   '.' ('0'..'9')+ EXPONENT?
    |   ('0'..'9')+ EXPONENT
    ;

//    :  '"' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'"') )* '"'
//    :   '"' (~'"')* '"'
STRING
    :   '"' (~'"')* '"'
    ;

fragment
EXPONENT : ('e'|'E') ('+'|'-')? ('0'..'9')+ ;

fragment
HEX_DIGIT : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;

fragment
ESC_SEQ
    :   '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
    |   UNICODE_ESC
    |   OCTAL_ESC
    ;

fragment
OCTAL_ESC
    :   '\\' ('0'..'3') ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7')
    ;

fragment
UNICODE_ESC
    :   '\\' 'u' HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT
    ;

NEWLINE:    '\r'? '\n' {skip();} ;

WS:     (' '|'\t')+ {skip();} ;
```

And for this input:

```
status={name="Waiting";val=5}[ownerEmail1={email="dsa@fdsf.ds"} OR internalStatus={status="New"}],comments={type="fds"}[(internalStatus={status="Owned"} AND ownerEmail2={email="dsa@fds.ds"}) OR (role={type="Contributor"} AND status={status="Closed"})]
```

I'm getting:

```
line 1:67 [obj, subscription, filters, expression, or, and, atom, filter, arguments_in_brackets] mismatched input [@18,67:80='internalStatus',<11>,1:67] expecting  ROPAREN
line 1:157 [obj, subscription, filters, expression, or, and, atom, atom_expression, expression, or, and, atom, filter, arguments_in_brackets] mismatched input [@42,157:167='ownerEmail2',<11>,1:157] expecting ROPAREN
```

Can someone give me any clues why is this failing please? I've tried to rewrite it in many ways but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `WS` tokens in other lexer rules and are therefor skipping these tokens. This causes the lexer to discard these tokens entirely, and can then not be used in parser rules.

So, if you have a rule like:

```
WS : ' ' {skip();};
```

and then use this rule in `NOT`:

```
NOT : WS* 'NOT' WS*;
```

it causes the `NOT` token to be skipped as well.

If you're already skipping these `WS` chars, you don't need to include them in your other lexer rules: simply remove all `WS*` in other rules:

```
...
NOT : 'NOT';
...
```

*(also remove them from parser rules: all `skip`ped tokens from the lexer are never available in parser rules anyway!)*

Comment: @user1394066, you're welcome. Forgot to mention this: never rely too much on the interpreter: it disregards almost all embedded code (that is why `skip()` wasn't called in most cases in the interpreter, and it seemed to work!).

Comment: Right, that explains the different results in interpret and generated code, once again thanks a lot.